# Cannot edit null values in ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have searched this forum and it seems that there is no other threat about my problem.

Well I have a gridview that has a number of fields. Some of them are NULL.

If I press edit and edit a field that is NOT NULL and press save then the information is correctly altered. If I choose a field that is NULL then,

NO information is saved.

I will include some of my SQL query and the piece of the code that does the problem.

Please if you know I will apriciate your help

SQL Query

```
   SELECT Request.column1,
    Request.column2, 
    Request.column3,
    Request.column4, 
    column5= isnull(Request.column5,'Select Date')
    FROM Reques
```

ASP Code for Column 5 that is the only one that has null fields and does the problem

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 5" SortExpression="column5">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                            DataTextField="column5" DataValueField="column5" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                                        SelectedValue='<%# Eval("column5") %>'>

                        </asp:DropDownList>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column5") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your DDL Appearing when it's having "Null" fields?  a collection of rows with both data and empty spaces?

What is your code showing as the value of the DDL when the rowDataBound is happening?
Did you try to see this from codebehind?

e.g. (vb.net)

```
Protected Sub mygrids_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As system.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles mygrids.RowUpdating

    Dim grv As GridViewRow = Me.mygrids.Rows(Me.mygrids.EditIndex)   ' find index of current edited row
    Dim dlltype As DropDownList = CType(grv.Cells(1).FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList)
    e.NewValues("TYP_ID") = dlltype.SelectedValue
```

(typ_ID) is the parameter i'm setting in my SQLDATASOURCE

Comment: I am taking the DDL data from another table, and there are no NULL values there. Therefore when I modify the already saved NULL value I always put value taken from another table and there are no nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste full code including the DataSource. But I would check following steps to make sure each are implemented.
1. See if you are handling Update/Save method on the datasource. See if the parameters are correctly set
2. See if you have set the DataKeyFieldName for the grid and for those particular columns where you are setting edit templates too.

Paste full code to have a detailed look